# React Router 4 Pass props to dynamic component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, dynamic-routing

I have a list of doctors and I am trying to dynamically render a details page when selected. I see most people recommend to pass props through the Route component, something like this:

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/:name`}
  component={ (props) => <DoctorView doctor={this.props.doctors} {...props} />}
  />
```

Though I'm not clear on where I should be executing this. I tried it in DoctorList and DoctorItem but that didn't work. So I've set the Route in the App component, and I am able select a doctor, which then renders the DoctorView component and display the match.params prop just fine. But how do I get the selected doctor data to DoctorView? I'm probably making this harder than it should be. Here is my code:

App.jsx

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <NavigationBar />
      <FlashMessagesList />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Greeting} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage} />
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
        <Route path="/content" component={requireAuth(ShareContentPage)} />
        <Route path="/doctors" component={requireAuth(Doctors)} />
        <Route path="/doctor/:name" component={requireAuth(DoctorView)} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

DoctorList.jsx

```
class DoctorList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { doctors } = this.props;
    const linkList = doctors.map((doctor, index) => {
      return (
        <DoctorItem doctor={doctor} key={index} />
      );
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Doctor List</h3>
        <ul>{linkList}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

DoctorItem.jsx

```
const DoctorItem = ({ doctor, match }) => (
  <div>
    <Link
      to={{ pathname:`/doctor/${doctor.profile.first_name}-${doctor.profile.last_name}` }}>
      {doctor.profile.first_name} {doctor.profile.last_name}
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

DoctorView.jsx

```
const DoctorItem = ({ doctor, match }) => (
  <div>
    <Link
      to={{ pathname:`/doctor/${doctor.profile.first_name}-${doctor.profile.last_name}` }}>
      {doctor.profile.first_name} {doctor.profile.last_name}
    </Link>
  </div>
);
```

I have access to the list of doctors via Redux, I could connect the component, bring in the list and compare id’s but that feels like a lot of unnecessary steps.

Comment: you want the whole doctor object right? not just the name?

Comment: Correct. Doctors is an array of doctor objects received from an external API request. I want to display all the details from the selected doctor's object. I was able to render all the details in the DoctorList component, but I would like to display them in a separate view instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do I get the selected doctor data to DoctorView?

Keep in mind that having paths like `/items` and `/items/:id` creates a scenario where you might be landing on the details page first.

Do you:

a) fetch all the items anyways because you might go back to the list page?

b) just fetch that the information for that one item?

Neither answer is "correct" but at the end of the day you have three possible pieces of information:

1) the item id

2) a single item

3) a list of items (which may or may not contain all of the information you need for the details page)

Wherever you want to display the full details of an item, it needs to have access to that item via props. Putting all of the item details in the url would be arduous, plus it would make it impossible to do situation A.

Since you're using redux, it makes perfect sense grab the details of the item from the identifier in the url

```
export default 
  connect((state, props) => ({
    doctor: state.doctorList.find(doctor => 
      doctor.id === props.match.params.id
    )
  }))(DoctorView)
```

Does ^ seems like too many extra steps?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, and it does make sense comparing id's now. Forgive me for being naive as I am striving to learn React/Redux, I'm not sure how implement the example you provided. Do I create a container, compare id's and pass matching doctor to the view component or compare them in the DoctorView posted in my question?

Comment: Thank you Azium! I was able to receive the matching doctor's object. You were absolutely right, not an extra step at all. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

While the answer above solves the issue perfectly, I just want to add that using an inline function with `component` is not advised by [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route)

Instead of doing:

```
<Route path={`${match.url}/:name`}
  component={ (props) => <DoctorView doctor={this.props.doctors} {...props} />}
  />
```

You should instead use it like:

```
 <Route path={`${match.url}/:name`}
  render={ (props) => <DoctorView doctor={this.props.doctors} {...props} />}
  />
```

This will prevent the same component from being created on every mount and instead use the same component and update the state accordingly.

Hope this will help someone